# Tic Tac Toe,Python, Index already filled problem

Tags: python

I have been trying to solve this code from the past few days where if I by mistake place my symbol("x" or "o") in the index already containing symbol, then it should display message "index already filled!", the problem is that it is showing that message even for the indexes which aren't filled. I am a beginner, please help me with this code and please answer my question with your code since i'm kind of bad at English.

```py
import numpy

board=numpy.array([["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"]])

numpy.matrix(board)

def pos(row,col,symbol,altr):

    while(board[row][col]==symbol or board[row][col]==altr):
        print("index already filled")
        place(symbol,altr)
    board[row][col]=symbol
    return board

def place(symbol,altr):

    c=int(input("enter index: "))
    if(c==1):
         return pos(0,0,symbol,altr)
    elif(c==2):
         return pos(0,1,symbol,altr)
    elif(c==3):
         return pos(0,2,symbol,altr)
    elif(c==4):
         return pos(1,0,symbol,altr)
    elif(c==5):
         return pos(1,1,symbol,altr)
    elif(c==6):
         return pos(1,2,symbol,altr)
    elif(c==7):
        return pos(2,0,symbol,altr)
    elif(c==8):
         return pos(2,1,symbol,altr)
    elif(c==9):
         return pos(2,2,symbol,altr)
def won(symbol):

    return check_rows(symbol) or check_cols(symbol) or check_diagnols(symbol)
def check_rows(symbol):

    for i in range(3):
        count=0
        for j in range(3):
            if(board[i][j]==symbol):
                count+=1
        if(count==3):
            return True
    else:
        return False
def check_cols(symbol):

    for j in range(3):
        count=0
        for i in range(3):
            if(board[i][j]==symbol):
                count+=1
        if(count==3):
            return True
    else:
        return False
def check_diagnols(symbol):

    if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] and board[1][1]==board[2][2] and board[2][2]==symbol):
        return True
    if(board[0][2]==board[1][1] and board[1][1]==board[2][0] and board[2][0]==symbol):
        return True
    return False

def play():

    p1=input("player1,enter your name: ")
    p2=input("player2,enter your name: ")
    pl1="x"
    pl2="o"
    i=0
    while(i<9):
        if(i%2==0):
            print(board)
            print(p1,"your turn")
            place(pl1,pl2)
            if(won(pl1)):
                print(board)
                print(p1,"you won")
                break
        else:
            if(i%2==1):
                print(board)
                print(p2,"your turn")
                place(pl2,pl1)
                if(won(pl2)):
                    print(board)
                    print(p2,"you won")
                    break
        i+=1
    if not won(pl1) and not won(pl2):
        print(board)
        print("draw")
```

Comment: Just a clarification: It seems that if players _never_ use a duplicate number then the game works as expected. However, if one player uses an index that exists then all the future inputs result in "index already filled"

Comment: The problem is your pos function calling place when the square is already filled in a while loop. I don't think pos should call place again, it should return False or similar and the calling code should call place, but you can make it work if you change the while loop to an if and return from pos without setting the square in that case.

Comment: You have another similar problem, though: what happens if the user enters a square number out of the range 1-9? I think they end up skipping their go, not being prompted for a valid number. And you also don't need the long `if(c==1) ... elsif (c==2)` to map c to row and col; you can use /3 and %3 on `c-1`, provided c is >=1 and <=9.

Comment: @trincot, OK, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` is not appropriate: the condition's result will *never* change, no matter how many times you loop. So effectively it is an infinite loop: once you get in, you never get out again.

It should be an `if`. And secondly, when the `if` condition is true, you don't want the execution of `board[row][col]=symbol` with those values of `row` and `col`. You should let that assignment happen through the recursive call of `place`. That execution will come to this function with (hopefully) better values of `row` and `col`, and will take care of putting the value in the board. So, ... you need to put that assignment in an `else` block, so it only happens when the location is fine.

```
    if (board[row][col]==symbol or board[row][col]==altr):
        print("index already filled")
        place(symbol,altr)
    else:
        board[row][col]=symbol
```

Remark: Even though it works like this, I would not have chosen for the recursive solution. You may want to look at an alternative where you have no recursion, but a `while` loop in the `place` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is place call pos, and pos call place, again and again. It's not necessary to return board in both functions.

```
def pos(row,col,symbol,altr):

    if board[row][col]==symbol or board[row][col]==altr:
        print("index already filled")
        return False
    else:
        board[row][col]=symbol
        return True

def place(symbol,altr):

    while True
        c=int(input("enter index: "))
        if 1 <= c <= 9:
            c = c-1
            if pos(c//3, c%3, symbol, alter):
                return
```

I explained this with pseudo code

```py
def pos(row, column, player_symbol, another_player_sumbol):
    # Check (row, cell) if not occupied
    if selected_cell not with blank syambol:
        message('Cell occupied')
        return input_is_NG
    else:
        set cell occupied
        return input_is_OK

def place(symbol,altr):

    while True (until position_is_OK):
        input position of cell
        if position is from 1 to 9:
            position -= 1
            if pos(position//3, position%3, symbol, alter) is OK:
                return # exit from place, and next turn for another player
        user_input_is_NG, while loop again
```

Comment: Thank you! this code really works, but could you please explain how the while loop doesn't break and still executes and takes input when the pos function returns false value.

Comment: The while loop again and again. Start from read input, check input if in the range of 1 to 9, then caluclate the row, column, call pos to check if board at row/column occupied or not. If occupied return False, it not, change the content of board, and return True. If return True, means OK, then break loop by return, else do nothing, means loop again.

Comment: thank you!, i m kind of beginner and read that while loop stops when function returns false value. So if row or column in board is occupied,then it returns false value.Then while loop must actually stop which it doesn't. why does it happen. please explain.

Comment: if board[row, column] is occupied, then pos returns False, then while keep to input again. Only board[row, column] not occupied, input is valid and pos return True, then returen (or break while loop, means end input and next player.